# fwrite and fread structs

Tags: c, struct, fwrite, fread

I want to write this struct into a binary file and then read it back from the binary file, but it doesn't work. The struct `tLista` has an array of `impresora`, and `impresora` have a `tCola` struct. The value of `l->oc` is `256883222` and obviously is incorrect. This value depends on the `loadData` function.

```
typedef char tcadena[13];

typedef struct 
{   
    tcadena nombres [TAM];
    int lectura;
    int escritura;
}tCola; 

typedef struct 
{
    char nombre [21];
    int pendientes;
    tCola cola;
}impresora;

typedef struct 
{
    impresora lista[TAMI];
    int oc;
}tLista;

...

void finalizar(tLista *l)
    {
    /* Apertura del fichero de destino, para escritura en binario*/
    FILE *fichero;
    fichero = fopen ("listaImpresoras.bin", "wb");
    if (fichero==NULL)
    {
        printf("No se puede abrir listaImpresoras.bin");
    }
    else
    {
        fwrite(l, sizeof(*l), 1, fichero);
    }
    fclose(fichero);
}

...

void inicializarLista (tLista *l)
{ 
    FILE *fichero;
    fichero=fopen("listaImpresoras.bin", "r");
    if(fichero==NULL)
    {
        printf("No existe el fichero listaImpresoras.bin\n");
        l->oc=0;
    }
    else
    {
        fread(l, sizeof(*l), 1, fichero);
    }
    fclose(fichero);
}

...

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    tLista l;
    inicializarLista(&l);
    loadData(&l); //printf and scanf (user) charge the list
    finalizar(&l);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And `donde está la función` `loadData()`?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `"rb"` mode when reading? Also, have you verified that the file you're reading from contains valid data (e.g. by looking at it in a hex editor)?

Comment: loadData only charge the data in the struct tLista

Comment: @Michale AFAIK the `b` is just for compatibility with `C89` standard.

Comment: with rb, i have the same value of l->oc, infinite :(

Comment: Since `loadData()` is called before `finalizar`, and `finalizar` writes the modified `tList l` to the file, you should post `loadData()`.

Comment: loadData() works, and fwrite write in the bin file the tLista struct but the value of l->oc is incorrect, but, if i make printf("%i", l->oc); the value is correct.

Comment: Then what makes you say the `l->oc` value is incorrect?

Comment: When I write with finalizar(), the bin file contains value 2392092902 in l->oc, then, when i use inicializarLista() function, l->oc charge with the value 2392092902

Comment: Add this right after the declaration `tList l;` -> `memset(&l, 0, sizeof(l));` do you observe the same behavior?

Comment: l is null, dont charge, l==NULL, iharob

Comment: That wouldn't do that. It will initialize all the bytes in the `struct` to `0`.

Comment: Yes, l is null with the memset :S

Comment: It's not... trust me, read the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html). And why dont you post the `loadData` function, is there something you don't want me to see?

Comment: loadData set l->oc++ and set the values in the others fields, only.

Comment: And what is the initial value of `l->oc`? you should post that function, there is the error.

Comment: in the function inicializarLista() if the file not exists, l->oc=0, else l->oc is charged with the file

Comment: True, but just try what I told you, there is nothing to loose...

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of problems, but the main problem, is you don't initialize the `tList l;` struct properly, below I post some code that may help you see the problem, it works I tested it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAM 100
#define TAMI 100

typedef char tcadena[13];

typedef struct
{
    tcadena nombres[TAM];
    int lectura;
    int escritura;
}tCola;

typedef struct
{
    char nombre[21];
    int pendientes;
    tCola cola;
}impresora;

typedef struct
{
    impresora lista[TAMI];
    int oc;
}tLista;

void finalizar(tLista *l)
{
    /* Apertura del fichero de destino, para escritura en binario*/
    FILE *fichero;

    fichero = fopen ("listaImpresoras.bin", "w");
    if (fichero == NULL)
    {
        printf("No se puede abrir listaImpresoras.bin");
    }
    else
    {
        fwrite(l, sizeof(*l), 1, fichero);
        /* solo debes llamar fclose(fichero); si (fichero != NULL) */
        fclose(fichero);
    }
    /* fclose(fichero); esto va a ser ejecutado, aunque (fichero == NULL) */
}

void inicializarLista(tLista *l)
{
    FILE *fichero;

    fichero = fopen("listaImpresoras.bin", "r");
    if (fichero == NULL)
    {
        printf("No existe el fichero listaImpresoras.bin\n");
        l->oc = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        fread(l, sizeof(*l), 1, fichero);
        /* solo debes llamar fclose(fichero); si (fichero != NULL) */
        fclose(fichero);
    }
    /* fclose(fichero); esto va a ser ejecutado, aunque (fichero == NULL) */
}

void loadData(tLista *l)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        l->oc++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    tLista l;

    /* tienes que iniacializar todos los campos de `l`. */
    memset(&l, 0, sizeof(l));
    /* si no quieres hacerlo asi, entonces puede que
     *
     * l.oc = 0;
     *
     * sea suficiente, pero quedan los otros campos.
     *
     * al no inicializar explicitamente los campos, contienen
     * basura aleatoria, que has estado escribiendo en el archivo.
     */                               

    inicializarLista(&l);
    printf("%d\n", l.oc);

    loadData(&l); //printf and scanf (user) charge the list

    finalizar(&l);
    return 0;
}
```

When you don't explicitly initialize all the fields in `tLista l;` they contain garbage, which you have been writing into the file.

Also if you check the success of `fopen()` why do you try to `fclose()` the resulting `NULL`? In case `fopen()` returns `NULL` you have to exit the function without `fclose`ing the result of `fopen` since it's `NULL`.

Comment: Sure iharob@gmail.com

Comment: Viste mi último mail, iharob?

Answer (score 1):

The code below:

- compiles cleanly,
- properly initializes the `tLista` struct,
- removes the obfuscation from the struct definitions,
- exits the program when an error occurs,
- properly writes the reason for the error to `stderr` before exiting.

Revised code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAM  (2)
#define TAMI (2)

struct tCola
{
    char nombres [TAM][13];
    int lectura;
    int escritura;
};

struct impresora
{
    char nombre [21];
    int pendientes;
    struct tCola cola;
};

struct  tLista
{
    struct impresora lista[TAMI];
    int oc;
};

void loadData( struct tLista *);

void finalizar(struct tLista *l)
{
    /* Apertura del fichero de destino, para escritura en binario*/
    FILE *fichero;

    if( NULL == (fichero = fopen ("listaImpresoras.bin", "wb") ) )
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror("fopen failed");
        printf("No se puede abrir listaImpresoras.bin\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    fwrite(l, sizeof(struct tLista), 1, fichero);
    fclose(fichero);
}  // end function: finalizar



void inicializarLista (struct tLista *l)
{
    FILE *fichero;

    if( NULL == (fichero=fopen("listaImpresoras.bin", "r") ) )
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror(" fopen failed");
        printf("No existe el fichero listaImpresoras.bin\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    fread(l, sizeof(*l), 1, fichero);
    fclose(fichero);
} // end function: inicializarLista



int main()
{
    struct tLista l;

    memset( &l, 0x00, sizeof(struct tLista) );
    inicializarLista(&l);
    loadData(&l); //printf and scanf (user) charge the list
    finalizar(&l);
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: Can I send You the complete code? I cant charge l->oc value on the binary file :(

Comment: sizeof(struct tLista) dont work: [Error] invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct tLista'